# How to add Flyway to an existing database without a DDL script?

Tags: flyway, kotlin-exposed

I currently have a Kotlin-Exposed project that I would like to add Flyway to. The problem I am having is that most documentation and answers online indicate that the best way to add Flwyay to an existing schema is to just have the first script be a data definition script. This usually would work, but since I'm dynamically generating my SQL with an ORM, this doesn't really make sense. Are there ways around this?

I really just want to use Flyway to add/delete persistent data that I will always need in certain tables. I don't want to insert it at the ORM level because if the application is run multiple times, then it can insert the data each time it's run (as opposed to Flyway where it will just migrate the database to the newest constructed state).

Answer (score 0):

I think another way to word this question is: "Can I use Flyway for static data only, and not schema?"

Yes, you can.

Some info:

- You are not required to have a first script containing the data definition / "baseline" of the schema. You can simply skip that.
- When running Flyway against a non-empty database for the first time, you will still need to run the [baseline command](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/v6/command/baseline). In your case this will simply indicate to Flyway that it can assume the baseline schema is present and that it's safe to run migrations. (Your baseline schema was deployed by the ORM instead of a baseline script -- that's totally fine, Flyway won't check/doesn't care.)
- You could choose to write your scripts that insert static data in a way that they are idempotent / use a guard clause so that they don't insert the data twice. That way it would be safe to use at the ORM level if you choose.